# IIS Url rewrite using Application_BeginRequest slow

Tags: c#, asp.net, performance, iis

I have implemented a complex url rewrite (that can not be achieved only with regex based rule in web config) implementing the handler Application_BeginRequest of my ASP.NET project.

I know it doesn't provide much information but the code in Application_BeginRequest is the subsequent.

```
    protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //check if rewrite is disabled
        if (ServiceLocator.AppConfigProvider.Instance.IsUrlRewriteEnabled == false)
            return;

        //check if it's an API URL a Data URL (custom, static or data) or Backoffice (only page url have to be rewritten)
        string[] segments = Request?.Url?.Segments ?? new string[0];
        if (segments.Length >= 2)
        {
            string rootSegment = (segments[1] ?? string.Empty).Replace("/", string.Empty).ToLower().Trim();

            if (rootSegment == "api" || rootSegment == "backoffice" || rootSegment == "custom" || rootSegment == "data" || rootSegment == "static")
                return;
        }

        var navigator = SiteNavigator.Instance();

        string absoluteUri = Request?.Url?.AbsoluteUri ?? string.Empty;
        var siteLocation = navigator.RewriteExternalUrl(absoluteUri);

        string internalUrl = siteLocation.ToString();
        HttpContext.Current.RewritePath(internalUrl);
    }
```

- If i test on my local system with IIS Express each call is incredibly
  slow (form previous 0,3-0,4s  to actual 3-4s so a slowdown of ~10x).
- If i test it with profiler the slowdown basically disappear (i do not
  change compilation mode, i still compile in debug mode but with
  profiler active).
- If i publish on a IIS (not Express) the slowdown disappear.
- If i go back to first test (the slow one) and disable my custom logic
  (IsUrlRewriteEnabled  == false) the slowdown disappear.
- If i go back to first test and with my custom logic active, i place a
  stopwatch and a counter (to check how many times and how long my
  logic take) i get that the code was hit twice in worst case scenario
  (redirect) and does not take more than 1ms foreach run.

So i am really confused about the behaviour, and have no idea how to test for the cause of slow down on my system.
I am concerned that i miss something in the picture of how things are working, so that the code seems fast when on IIS (not express) but the issue is still present, and maybe it could create problem when released in production environment.

Note :
i still use few regex base rule, mainly to rewrite url that does not use HTTPS here the list of regex base rules

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Redirect to https" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url=".*" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" redirectType="Permanent" appendQueryString="false" />
    </rule>
    <rule name="Login" enabled="false" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^login.*" />
      <action type="Rewrite" url="/Pages/login.aspx" appendQueryString="false" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Comment: Could you identify which rule is causing the slow call issue? You can use the elimination process to see if there is a specific process that is causing the problem.

Comment: @YurongDai except for HTTPS i don't use regex rule. And activating/deactivating regex rule does not change anything. The slowdown is almost ubiquitus (i have checked some random pages) but application execution time is really low (few ms), response time otherhand is slow. It smell like a routing issue i get on IIS Express only (probably because full IIS is more reliable) but i would like to solve it (i don't want to put a lame architecture into production environment

Comment: @YurongDai after a lot of testing turn out that there is a silent exception (that for some reason is not triggered even if i setup Visual Studio to break on every exception) that is raised a gazilion of times for each request (due to an errore in rewrite when there is a url referrer) that slow down IIS Express. I don't know why the same problem doesn't raise also in IIS (standard)

Comment: It is difficult to reproduce your problem only based on your description, I suggest you open a case via: https://support.microsoft.com.